# displaying images horizontally is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display images horizontally and it is not working for me. I want to display 8 images next to each other. I know I am doing something wrong with my grid system. Right now they are being displayed one below another and I want them to be horizontal. If I do `col-md-1` or `col-md-2` it becomes off. How do I fix this ? thanks in advance!

this is what I have.

```
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon01_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon02_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon03_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon04_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon05_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon06_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/LogoIcon07_over.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="pics/ViewBrandsButton.png" alt="160x66" >
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Seriously who did upvote this? **FYI:** `<img>`s *are* inline-level elements, they sit beside each other just like words. This means you don't have to put each one in a separate column. Besides there's no such `col-md-1.5` thing in TWBS.

Comment: Please show us your css code.

Comment: post your CSS too....

Comment: I don't have any css

Comment: @HashemQolami well how do I divide them when there's eight of them in the row...(edit)..I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, there is no column class that equals 12.5% or 1/8 of 100%. Images are inline automatically. To fit these images to be on a single line at the min-width of 992px (col-md-x), this is one way of doing it. If you use the .thumb class around these, you'll need to change it to inline-block or inline since a div is a block element.

*Demo: http://jsbin.com/yivavo/1/*

**CSS:**

```
.my-images {font-size:0;}/*remove white space for inline elements */
.my-images img {padding:2px}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .my-images img {width:12.5%;height:auto;}  
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="my-images text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/166x60/444444/FFFFFF&text=image" alt="">
   </div>
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! I totally see what I did wrong...

Comment: add the height: auto for ie. Might want to test in ie8 before you go far.